# how do I sort a two dimensional array in the second dimension (comporator does not work because the same numbers appear several times)?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array, in the first dimension are letters, in the second numbers, I wanted to sort by the numbers in the second dimension, the problem is that I have problems because the same number occurs several times, in the numbers that do not occur twice, it is sorted correctly, from the moment where a double number occurs, not.At least I have with a comporator the problen

I tried this, to sort, with this comparator method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] test = new String[5][2];
    test[0][0] = "a";
    test[1][0] = "a";
    test[2][0] = "a";
    test[3][0] = "a";
    test[4][0] = "a";
    test[0][1] = "1";
    test[1][1] = "2";
    test[2][1] = "1";
    test[3][1] = "3";
    test[4][1] = "4";
    Comparator<String[]> test2 = new Comparator<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) > Integer.parseInt(o1[1])) {
                return 1;
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) < Integer.parseInt(o1[1])) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    };

    Arrays.sort(test, test2);

    for (String[] t : test) {
        System.out.println(t[1]);
    }

}
```

The output is:

1

2

1

3

4

Same numbers makes problems... With out a same number correctly

1

2

3

4
would be the output...

(correct output from the example needed to be:

1

1

2

3

4

)

Comment: From ur example, i don't fully get what ur trying to do(or how it even makes tbh) could you include example input / expected output?

Comment: I added you are a example. When you have a String in the first dimension you have letters, in the second numbers, i wanted to sort it with the numbers, but by numbers which are the same and two times in the array, i have problems

Comment: I wanted an example of the actual input values and the expected output

Comment: ah sorry okay moment

Comment: Now I added a example, with input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yields the correct output:

```java
        String[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(test)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])))
                .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

How it works should be pretty self explanatory, if something is unclear let me know and i can clarify.

If u just want to modify the existing array then:

```java
Arrays.sort(test, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])));
```

The issue in ur existing code was that u weren't using o2, so the comparisons didn't really make any sense.

The working version would be be:

```java
        Comparator<String[]> test2 = new Comparator<String[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) > Integer.parseInt(o2[1])) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) < Integer.parseInt(o2[1])) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };
```

Which is equivalent to:

```java
        Comparator<String[]> test2 = (o1, o2) -> {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1[1]), Integer.parseInt(o2[1]));
        };
```

Simplified even more:

```java
Comparator<String[]> test2 = Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o[1]));
```

Comment: What is the ->? I see this the first time

Comment: Sorry it not works the same numbers are not included... Normally when i have for exampke 1,2,3,4,1 it needs to be sorted: 1,1,2,3,4 now we have 1,2,3,4,

Comment: -> is syntax for lambda expression, also wym same numbers are not included? i ran the code with ur test input and it outputs 1, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Oh! YOU ARE RIGHT, SORRY!

Comment: You code work, but what is the different, between your code and my code?

Comment: Read my answer, i explained what was wrong with ur current solution, other than simplifying, the only difference is the mistake u made in ur code.

Comment: ohh you are true!